How can I approximate 255/sqrt(x) using Newton's method?
I am trying to approximate 255 / sqrt(x) using Newton's method to avoid using division or the sqrt() operation on an architecture where those operations are expensive.
My derivation is:
y = 255 / sqrt(x)
255 / y^2 = x
f(y) = 255 / y^2 - x = 0
y[n+1] = y[n] - f(y) / f’(y)
f’(y) = -510 / y^3
y[n+1] = y[n] - (255 / y[n]^2 - x) / (-510 / y[n] ^ 3)
y[n+1] = 3/2 * y[n] - x * y[n]^2 / 510

I tested this with the following code
# what I want is 255 * isqrt(x) or 255 / sqrt(x)
def inverse_sqrt_newton_255(x, iterations=5):
    y = 255. / x
    for _ in range(iterations):
        y = (1.5 * y) - (x * y * y / 510.)
    return y

However, I find that the result is always off by a factor of sqrt(x)
inverse_sqrt_newton_255(25) = 10.2 (should be 51)
I could obviously multiply the result by sqrt(x) but the whole point is to avoid the sqrt() operation.
For reference, the following works correctly for computing 1 / sqrt(x):
def inverse_sqrt_newton(x, iterations=5):
    y = 1.0 / x
    for _ in range(iterations):
        y = y * (1.5 - 0.5 * x * y * y)
    return y

What am I doing wrong?

Have you tested your code? Just because hardware division is slower than, say, multiplication doesn't mean your Python implementation mirrors that. (If you're worried about hardware division being slow, I'm not sure why you are using pure Python in the first place.)

In the second line 255 / y^2 = x, the 255 should be squared too, shouldn't it?

I'm using python to simulate what I would be doing on another platform that's harder to test on, to make sure my math is right

re: VPfB, yes, you're exactly right, and that solves it. I'll update the question for posterity.

per a comment, my math was wrong.
Updated math:
Y = 255 / sqrt(x)
255 / y = sqrt(x)
(255 / y)^2 = x 
255^2 / y^2 = x
f(y) = 255^2 / y^2 - x = 0
Y[n+1] = y[n] - f(y) / f’(y)
F’(y) = -2 * 255^2 / y^3
y[n+1] = y[n] - (255^2 / y[n]^2 - x) / (-2 * 255^2 / y^3)
y[n+1] = y[n] - ((x * y[n]^3) - (255^2 * y[n]) / (2 * 255^2)

This results in the following code, which works
def inverse_sqrt_newton_255(x, iterations=5):
    y = 255. / x
    for _ in range(iterations):
        # works:
        # y = y - (255**2 / y**2 - x) / (-2 * 255**2 / y**3)

        # works, but dividing by a constant
        y = y - ((x * y**3) - (255**2 * y)) / (2 * 255**2)
    return y


It will be faster if you replace / (2 * 255**2) with / 130050 or with * 7.689350249903884e-06

the compiler would do that automatically
